# Why is Shapely's snapping (GEO snaps) not working as expected?

Tags: shapely, snapping, geopandas

I'm trying to snap two lines to each other using Shapely/Geopandas but the result of the snapping is very odd.
I tried :

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import *
from shapely.ops import snap

lines1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file('lines1.shp')
lines1 = lines1.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:2227'})
lines2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file('lines2.shp')
lines2 = lines2.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:2227'})
res = lines1
lines2_union = lines2.geometry.unary_union
res.geometry = res.geometry.apply(lambda x: snap(x, lines2_union, 14))
res.to_file('result.shp', driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```

And got this result :

**lines1** = **red** lines

**lines2** = **black** lines

[image: Before the snapping]

After the snapping(with 14 as a tolerance) :
the **blue** lines are the result of the snapping

In this case the lines are correctly snapped
[image: After the snapping]

Another example where it didn't work as expected: (before the snapping)
[image: Before the snapping]

And here's the result after the snapping. Only a part is snapped to the black line (the south side). Although the original lines are pretty close and within the 14 feets
[image: After the snapping]

If I increase the tolerance I get a wrong output, something like this (after defining 20 as the tolerance of the snapping, the green line is the result):

[image: After 20 as a tolerance]

Any ideas on why the snapping is not working properly? 
Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Perhaps a an issue of precision (see   [Why are the symmetric_difference and intersection operations for the Shapely.Geometry library apparently inconsistent?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32040758/835653))

Comment: @gene you should convert your comment to an answer I think.

Comment: Can you share the data or parts of it to reproduce this issue?

Comment: Provided Shapely 1.6 User Manual: "The snap() function in shapely.ops snaps the vertices in one geometry to the vertices in a second geometry with a given tolerance." As I understand, It doesn't snaps geometries that are close to each others, it snaps their vertices close to each other. So if any geometry is close to other geometry, it snaps their vertices within threshold.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `shapely.ops.snap` function snaps to the vertices of geometries only.

See the illustration below. On the left, the red vertex is within the snapping tolerance to the blue vertex, so it will snap. On the right the red vertex is outside the snapping tolerance (despite being closer to the edge!).

[image: snapping tolerance visualisation]

Shapely doesn't provide an algorithm for snapping vertices to edges. It shouldn't be too difficult to write one using `shapely.ops.nearest_points` though. Something like this (not tested, and not especially efficient):

```
from shapely.ops import nearest_points

def snap(g1, g2, threshold):
    coordinates = []
    for x, y in g1.coords:  # for each vertex in the first line
        point = Point(x, y)
        p1, p2 = nearest_points(point, g2)  # find the nearest point on the second line
        if p1.distance(p2 <= threshold):
            # it's within the snapping tolerance, use the snapped vertex
            coordinates.append(p2.coords[0])
        else:
            # it's too far, use the original vertex
            coordinates.append((x, y))
    # convert coordinates back to a LineString and return
    return LineString(coordinates)
```

Comment: Very cool but I think `if p1.distance(p2 <= threshold):` should be `if p1.distance(p2) <= threshold:`