# How to perfectly snap the boundaries of contiguous polygons?

Tags: qgis, python, shapely, snapping

I want to perfectly snap the boundaries of contiguous polygons using Python and QGIS. However, I don't want the polygons to merge into a single polygon.

I have tried to snap the polygons using `shapely` as follows:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from shapely.ops import snap

snap(polygon_one, polygon_two, 2)
```

However, the points don't snap well. This may be due to the fact that the snapping function only adjusts the points and not create new points. As the coordinates of polygons are generated using an automated process, the number of coordinates for both polygons are different and are not consistent as well. Therefore, I am unable to achieve the desired snapping results. Consider the following images of snapped polygons.

[image: Snapped Polygons]
[image: Snapped Polygons]
[image: Snapped Polygons]

Please note that some coordinates are merged perfectly but the polygons are still overlapping in some areas and have gaps between them in other areas. Is there an alternative and efficient technique for doing this?

Comment: The *only* way to achieve a "perfect snap" is to merge the features then extract them (and even then storage issues might shift them out of perfect alignment).

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to improve the snapping results as compared to the results presented above?

Comment: The QGIS Snap Geometries to Layer tool has several behavior options you could choose from.  You can also use in QGIS the GRASS v.clean and choose a snapping tolerance.  If there are overlaps larger than the tolerance you can follow that tool with the Delete Duplicate Geometries tool.

Comment: See     [Why is Shapely's snapping (GEO snaps) not working as expected?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/279255/2581)